# Why postgresql execute less commit when get more queries

Tags: postgresql

client is nodejs with pg library.

I send separately 100,000 and 500,000 easy select queries asynchronously.

first one is 100,000 queries, total execute time is about 20s
[image]

second one is 500,000 queries,total execute time is about 200s
[image]

1. why 10 times slow when I send only 5 times more queries?
2. why execute less commits in early stage when send 500,000 queries?
3. How could change this situation and make commits execution more average?

Comment: A combination of available hardware resources and configuration.

Comment: 1) If these are simple selects why have commits at all? 2) Provide the  `pg` code you are using to run the queries **as text(not images) update to your question text**. 3) Best bet is that the queries are stacking up somewhere in the process and the bulk hit the database at the end.

Comment: The IO curve looks to me like the 2nd one had some trouble getting the cache warmed up until right near the end.  Why that would be would depend entirely on things you haven't told us.